# WebRTC is not supported in Chrome and Edge

Tags: webrtc, agora.io, simplewebrtc

Hi I've implemented a video call using WebRTC / Agora.io.

It was working well until last week I get this message.

It doesn't support now in Chrome and Edge. But is still working on Mozilla Firefox.

Anyone also encounter this issue? There's no error in the console logs and network tab.

[image]

Comment: Is supported in chrome mate, check your configurations, it was made on the heart of chrome

Comment: In February they sent emails to developer community warning about the Chrome patches that would cause this issue from April '22. They suggested to stay with     "agora-rtc-sdk": "3.6.10". or upgrade to sdk 4.x (not backward compatible). Personally, my issue is not solved since I'm reluctant to upgrade to 4.x since it requires redesign of my software. I'm trying to make it work with 'npm i agora-rtc-sdk@3.6.10'. I am still trying. But that's what their documentation says.

Comment: @IshwaraBhat , were you able to solve the problem using 3.6.10 ?

Comment: @SergeyGlazyrin I went on to upgrade. This article works very well.  https://blog.learningdollars.com/2022/03/29/how-to-build-a-video-app-using-angular-and-agora-rtc/

Comment: In case you do not want to upgrade, check this thread. https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Angular-Agora-RTC/issues/52